# Spark SQL - pyspark api vs sql queries

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

All,

I have question regarding writing SparkSQL program, is there difference of performance between writing

1. `SQLContext.sql("select count(*) from (select distinct col1,col2 from table))")`
2. using pyspark Api : `df.select("col1,col2").distinct().count()`.

I would like to hear out the suggestion and correct way to convert very large queries like ( 1000 lines ) joining 10+ tables  to Py-Spark program

I am from SQL background and we are working on converting existing logic to hadoop, hence SQL is handy.